# Являются ли Spring beans потоконезависимыми?

Tags: spring, scope

Господа, верно ли я понимаю, что Spring бины с scope=session являются аналогом EJB stateful бинов, и посему в Spring заложено их потоконезависимое поведение?

А что можно сказать о потоконезависимости singleton и prototype бинов? Можно ли их править из разных потоков?

Кстати, какими средствами эта потоконезависимость реализована в Spring?

Очень всем признателен за разъяснения.

PS: возможно, я также неверное представляю себе, будто EJB stateful beans потоконезависимы

Comment: Это на плечах ПОГРОМиста.  Особенно синглтон бинов.

Answer (score 4):

> верно ли я понимаю, что Spring бины с `scope=session`

Бины со скоупом `session` в конечном счете лежат в `ThreadLocal<RequestAttributes>`.

> А что можно сказать о потоконезависимости singleton и prototype бинов? Можно ли их править из разных потоков?

Можно, но вся синхронизация, атомарность и волатильность - на вас. То есть спринг в данном случае ничего вам не обеспечивает.